# What should I do if my professor made a mistake on a quiz but refuses to fix it?

Tags: ethics, grading

After going through a quiz, I was surprised to see that we hadn't gone over half the material in class or in our reading. It was brought to the attention of the professor and she said she would take a look and consider the options. She saw that "most" did well regardless of the fact it was new material and decided to keep the quiz the way it was. 
I personally got a 73% on this quiz (which is a failing grade in my strenuous program) and my friend got a 50%. After talking to her privately she is continuing to stand by her choice. Should I go above her?

Comment: You're going to have a tough time convincing anyone because everyone else in the class was in the same position.

Comment: One of my concerns is that this is not the first time this has happened and I know it will not be the last. Do you think I should just ignore it?

Comment: There are a huge number of factors here. Does your university have an ombudsman? That would be the best first person to go to with your concerns, and it's also someone who could explain what the expectations are at your university.

Comment: You do not state whether the quiz covered material that is to be in the course syllabus, perhaps in an upcoming lecture or reading. You do not state whether you were told that you will ONLY be quizzed only on material that you are told about first or whether you should anticipate that you will be quizzed on material that is upcoming *even though the reading may have yet to be announced*. Finally, what is your reason to "go above her"? Giving a quiz that surprised you and your friend? Saying that she would review the options and then standing by her opening decision after that review?

Comment: I'm surprised that 73% can be a failing grade! Is this an UG course?

Answer (score 1):

Find out how some of the students who did well on the test managed it. There may be some pattern. For example, there could be another course that many of them have taken that covered the missing material. That would strengthen your case for some adjustment. On the other hand, if it is just paying more attention and doing more reading, you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

People writing here have incomplete information, of course. But from what you say it sounds like she should have to give a justification for the decision.

One way is to make a collective appeal to her directly. The fact that "most" did well means that, almost by definition, some were disadvantaged by the quiz. That needs compensation of some sort.

One way is to make a collective appeal to her superior, laying out the facts.

But an individual appeal to her has failed, apparently, and may fail to her superior as well. This seems to me to be a situation in which you need to get a group together, formulate your arguments, and then present them.

It is probably less confrontational if you take it first to her, as a group. If you don't get a satisfactory answer then escalate it.

However, if it is a very small part of grading, then maybe just ignoring it to avoid hassle would be justified.

Comment: I have to wonder, absent the information that I noted in my comment to the OP's post, whether your recommendation takes too much at face value in the OP's underlying appeal to right a seeming injustice and pays too little respect to the responsibility for the OP to put the situation in full context first. Also, I disagree with the if-this-then-that argument that if *only* "most" do well, then the instructor **needs** to compensate the disadvantaged. I sense a victim mentality creeping in. Finally, all the instructor needs to say is ... I reviewed the case and stand by my decision.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer, and I have to wonder whether this professor is too much focused on grading and too little focused on teaching. Of course instructors can be autocratic and often are.

Comment: Absent further information from the OP, we are both in the same place of having to wonder.